# Attribute Error 'module' object has no attribute 'ascii_letters'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why do I receive the error message in the title from the code below?

Edit: Cause I didn't pay attention to how I wrote "ascii". Thanks everyone

The code below works fine on my Iphone IDE but not on my Windows 7 (w/Notepad++ and Command Prompt). I checked the directory to see if any string.py files existed which I did not see any. I ran a search on my desktop and found 4 files named that, two of which said they were complied. I deleted the compiled files and left the other two. I'm a noob.

```
import string
import random

x = string.acsii_letters
y = random.choice(x)

print y * 5
```

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: @ChadSimmons python 2.7 per title

Comment: it is `ascii` not `acsii`

Comment: The error you'll get is `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'acsii_letters'` it's funny that you posted the correct "ascii" in the title tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `string.ascii_letters` letters instead of `string.acsii_letters`. If that's a typo in code statement here only, then your guess must be right, there is another string module in your `PYTHONPATH`. Open python shell,

```
import string
print(string.__file__)
```

to ensure string is being imported from right path. If its not remove that path from `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 2):

In python 3 I found that using the `string.ascii_letters` works as `string.letters` results in an AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. It should be `string.ascii_letters` or `string.letters`. You can look at the attributes of the string module with `dir(string)` and see what you can access.

Answer (score -1):

i  had the same issue the reason was that the name of the file is the same of the module name . so just rename your file the module will work well

Comment: This question has already been answered six years ago.