# An error occured while starting the kernel

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

for some reason my spyder isn't working anymore. when starting the spyder it shows the following error message in the console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 279, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 19, in 
import pdb
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 73, in 
import cmd
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\cmd.py", line 50, in 
IDENTCHARS = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_'
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32746028/5763413) and see where string is being imported from.

Comment: What did the fix end up being? It's good practice to document what the fix was for future visitors.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This usually happens because a file called `string,py` in your current working directory or your `C:\Users\hp` one. Please find it and rename it or remove it.